# What's the difference between 指摘する・指示する and 示す?

Tags: meaning, words, nuances

I know these verbs translate to "pointing out", "indicating" or "showing". I was just wondering what the nuance between these words mean.

Answer (score 3):

指示 and 示す are occasionally interchangeable, but 指摘 is very different from the others.

指摘 means "to point out" in the sense of telling someone some unmentioned or forgotten fact.

- 彼に私の欠点を指摘された。
- 忘れていました、指摘してくださってありがとうございます。

指示 means "to instruct, order" in most cases where it's used on its own. But it's sometimes used as a stiff kango version of 指し示す ("to indicate, to point (out)" in the sense of "specifying the target/object"), especially in [compounds](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%8C%87%E7%A4%BA).

- 部下に朝7時に出勤するよう指示した。
- 指示代名詞 demonstrative pronoun

示す basically just means "to mean, signify, tell, represent, show". It can mean "to point out" when the subject is something pointy (arrow, finger, a clock hand, etc.)

- 感謝の気持ちを示しましょう。
- 指を使って行き先を示した。
- 時計の針は5時を示している。